# Javascript for loop canvas drawing-go back to start x and y?

Tags: javascript, canvas, for-loop

Im using this

```
var gameMessages=20;
for (i=0,j=0;i<gameMessages;i++)
        {
        context.drawImage(spritesh,69,189,16,16,155+i*29,375+j,32,32);

        if(i==13)
        {

            j=j+32;

        }
    }
```

to draw a image gameMessages amount of times, what I would now need is that fhen the if statement kicks in, it would continue drawing the second row from the starting position 155. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gameMessages=20;
for (i=0,j=0,k=0;i<gameMessages;i++,k++)
    {
    context.drawImage(spritesh,69,189,16,16,155+k*29,375+j,32,32);

    if(i==13)
    {
        k=0;
        j=j+32;

    }
}
```